# Transparent avi in WPF MediaElement

Tags: wpf, opacity, mediaelement

I have a mediaelement tag in my wpf-window. It's playing a simple animation, similar to the windows xp copy file dialog.

The animation has an ugly pink background #FF00FF, that I want to be transparent. I've tried setting the color in the OpacityMask attribute, but the color remains. Any ideas on how I can remove the color from the video?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a shader effect to remove a specific color. Luckily this type of shader is part of the WPF Pixel Shader Effects Library - http://www.codeplex.com/wpffx which is available free of charge. The effect that you should look at is called ColorKeyAlpha.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0689e2b8-829e-4860-857b-b4755e0bc0e0) you can find more info on the subject and if you are new to shaders [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2008/05/12/a-series-on-gpu-based-effects-for-wpf.aspx) blog series has all the information you will need -